# C# - tem como rodar uma task e voltar para a thread principal depois?

Tags: c#, thread, multithreading, navegador-de-internet, task

no caso todo o programa é escrito sem task e apenas um trecho é com task, eu queria que depois desse pedaço ele voltasse para a "thread principal".
O codigo abaixo fica dentro de um for, e serve pra abrir uma janela de salvar, a task especificamente opera esta janela, ela inicia antes mesmo da janela ser aberta pois quando a mesma é aberta o programa "para de ler o codigo". Vale lembrar que a janela de salvar não é um savefileDialog, ela é aberta usando a ferramenta webbrowser do c# invocando um click num botao de baixar.

```
Clipboard.SetText(@"C:\ARQUIVOS\");

            Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                SendKeys.SendWait("{HOME}");
                SendKeys.SendWait("^{V}");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}"); //esse enter salva o arquivo, depois disso o programa fica em "standby" pois acaba a thread e nao volta para o codigo principal 
                Task.Delay(3000);

            });

            await Task.Delay(3000);

            SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");
            SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");
            SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");
            SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");  //abre janela de salvar
            FileIOPermission.RevertAll();  //permissões para a janela
            Task.Delay(3000);
```

**EDIT:** 
Consegui com o seguinte codigo:

```
    private async Task OperaJanelaSaveAs()
    {
        Clipboard.SetText(@"C:\ARQUIVOS\");

        SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");
        SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");
        SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");
        SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");  //abre janela de salvar
        await Task.Delay(4000);
        SendKeys.SendWait("{HOME}");
        SendKeys.SendWait("^{V}");    //cola o caminho do arquivo (clipboard) 
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}"); //salva o arquivo
        await Task.Delay(4000);
    }
```

e chamando a função com delay para esperar o click no botão de baixar e await

```
await Task.Delay(6000);
await OperaJanelaSaveAs();
```

Comment: isso está bem confuso, coloque seu código para entendermos melhor

Comment: E esse não é exatamente o motivo de usar uma `Task`?

Comment: @Maniero sim porém o codigo é terminado após a task

Comment: @RicardoPontual coloquei

Comment: Não vi sentido em usar essa task com a sua necessidade.

Comment: Esse monte de `Thread.Sleep()` já mostra que esse código não faz sentido e está fazendo coisas erradas. Não sabemos exatamente o que quer fazer, mas parece escolha errada

Comment: @VictorLaio como eu disse quando eu abro a janela de salvar o programa entende que nao tem mais codigo pra ler então a task ja está rodando e opera a janela

Comment: Sugiro não colocar dados sensíveis nos exemplos. Por exemplo o IP!

Comment: @phduarte Cara, é um IP local, não tem nada de sensível nisso.

Comment: @MiltonMachadoPereira Tente [edit] sua pergunta e ser mais claro. Explique o que você pretende fazer.

Comment: @LINQ ve se ficou melhor

Comment: @LINQ Se eu trabalhasse na mesma empresa agora eu saberia onde os arquivos de Cobrança ficam salvos!

Comment: @MiltonMachadoPereira essa janela que abre para salvar. Ela é uma página web ou uma janela do Windows?

Comment: @phduarte janela do windows aberta a partir de um botao de um site aberto na ferramenta webbrowser do c#

Comment: @MiltonMachadoPereira você provavelmente está usando essa Task porque não sabe exatamente o tempo que vai levar pra janela de Salvar aparecer, e não quer que o sistema fique em estado de "Não respondendo" ou algo assim. Correto?

Comment: @phduarte para esperar uso sleeps e delays. O Problema em questão é que depois que salva o arquivo não acontece mais nada, e como eu disse o codigo em questão está junto com mais codigo tudo dentro de um for e não está indo para a proxima repetição.

Comment: @MiltonMachadoPereira como não está tendo problema com o status Não respondendo e está usando Sleeps em vários trechos, não consigo ver o benefício de usar as multithread. Parece estar te atrapalhando mais do que ajudando. Eu normalmente faço coisas parecidas com isso de salvar arquivo usando thread, mas não uso Sleep nem SendKeys, faço usando api do próprio Windows, também uso uma variável booleana para controlar a conclusão antes de sequir a execução do código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olha... está muito confuso sua pergunta mas das informações que consegui retirar segue:
Isto se você tiver disponível .NET Framework 4.0+

```
public async Task DoWork()
{
    Clipboard.SetText(@"\\192.168.30.158\ARQUIVOS\");

    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        SendKeys.SendWait("{HOME}");
        SendKeys.SendWait("^{V}");
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}"); //esse enter salva o arquivo, depois disso o programa fica em "standby" pois acaba a thread e nao volta para o codigo principal 
        await Task.Delay(3000);
    });

    await Task.Delay(3000);

    SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");
    SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");
    SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");
    SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");  //abre janela de salvar

    FileIOPermission.RevertAll();  //permissões para a janela

    await Task.Delay(3000);
}
```

Comment: Cara, de forma assincrona (com seu codigo) eu consigo fazer o codigo continuar rodando depois que roda a task, porém não baixa o arquivo. e de forma sincrona eu consigo baixar o arquivo mas não consigo voltar para o codigo depois da task rodada. Acho que está esperando no momento errado usando o bloco de codigo que vc mandou.

Comment: Bem mais simples fazer functions do que tasks, principalmente por poder chamar a função novamente

Comment: @riki481 como mesmo citei, está muito confuso a pergunta. O máximo que consegui chegar com as informações que eu tinha e entendi, foi o código acima. Provavelmente, tem formas melhores de fazer mas não com as informações que recebi da pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Veja um exemplo para salvar arquivo voltando para o fluxo principal do sistema após execução da thread.

Com algumas modificações você pode adaptar ao seu cenário.

```cs
public void SalvarArquivo()
{
    //faz as ações antes de salvar o arquivo
    Console.WriteLine("Preparando arquivo para salvar");

    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        for (var i = 10; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            Console.Write("\rSalvando arquivo. Aguarde {0} segundos", i);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    });

    task.Wait();

    //faz as ações após conclusão
    Console.WriteLine("Arquivo salvo com sucesso.\nPressione Enter para sair.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

ou

```cs
async void Do()
{
    await SalvarArquivoAsync();
}

public async Task SalvarArquivoAsync()
{
    //faz as ações antes de salvar o arquivo
    Console.WriteLine("Preparando arquivo para salvar");

    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        for (var i = 10; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            Console.Write("\rSalvando arquivo. Aguarde {0} segundos", i);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    });

    //faz as ações após conclusão
    Console.WriteLine("Arquivo salvo com sucesso.\nPressione Enter para sair.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: preciso que a thread inicie de forma assincrona e termine sincrona